# Is it possible to use output from a script run on the packer provisioners to create tags for the generated AMI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, packer

I am using packer to generate AMIs that are preconfigured with some programs - both installed from apt and compiled from source. I would like to be able to tag the generated AMI with the versions of the installed programs but I can't figure out how I would do that.

On the provisioned machine I would run:

```
program --version
```

and get something like

```
v1.3
```

The problem is I'm not able to run this until after the machine is provisioned and install so I am unable to add that information to the template file prior to running packer build.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

for the software versions you know up ahead, you can use the tags property "amazon-ebs" builder.
if it's going to be dynamic/ install latest available version, then you can have a script that prints out the software version to a file and use the File provisioner 
with direction set to "download", so the file is available on the host.

Then you can read the file and run "aws ec2 create-tags"   command to add additional tags to the ami.